# How to add in a Flipping Book Publisher html file into the Product Image Section?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image, product-linking

I have the product Flipping Book Publisher and I have created a flipbook.

What I want to know is, is there any way to add this into where the static product image goes?

If not, how can I add this directly beneath the static product image instead of linking using code in the product description to the html file of the flipbook?

Or is it possible to make the static image a hyperlink?

I am still quite new to Magento so please use as much detail as possible. This is for the product pages not the cart page where you view the product.